# Simplify series of regex-based string replacements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

So I'm using `filter` in my angular app. This filter takes a string and coverts it to text. I have a multiple rules in this filter, because each string is a different. Each of this rules I defined step by step, like here:

```
 .filter('filter', function () {

        return function (item) {
            var space = item.replace(/\./g, " ");
            var result = space.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1");
            var ids = result.replace(/Id==/g, " ");
            var categories = ids.replace(/Id=in=\(/g, ' ');
            var text = categories.replace(/title==/g, 'title: ');
            var desc = text.replace(/description==/g, 'description: ');

            var dots = desc.replace(/\*/g, ' ');
            var parants = dots.replace(/\)/g, ' ');
            var commas = parants.replace(/\,/g, '');

            var equal = commas.replace(/=/g, '');
            var more = equal.replace(/>/g, '');
            var line = more.replace(/-/g, '');
            var semidots = line.replace(/:/g, '');

            var numbers = semidots.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');

            var final = numbers.replace(/Z/g, '');
            return final.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + final.slice(1)

        }
    })
```

and this is example of string

```
title==*test*;description==*some%20desciption*;eventTypeId==10;studyId==99999;priorityId==2;severityId==3;occuredDate%3E=2016-09-01T04:00:00.000Z
```

The final result is good enough and looks like:

[image: example of filter applied]

I'm sure this code can be more simple, but I'm not so good in regex, so my question is, how to make this regex rules more simple and beautiful? 
I appreciate any help.

This is simple [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YyVRvaR5u9G4ytaBxdgH?p=preview) with my example

Comment: You can `.split()` the string you're getting and break it into its own variables. You're using too many layers of regex right now.

Comment: You don't need all those intermediate variables. Just chain all of the statements together in one line (but then insert newlines in your code to make it easier to read)

Comment: If you want simple and beautiful, I'm afraid regex is not where you turn ;).

Comment: Can you please show the desired string output? It's not clear what you want from the picture alone.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I happen to strongly disagree, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from working on complicated regex, one approach you could take is to manage a list of mutations that are applied in sequence.

```js
function filter(item){
   var replacements = [];

   replacements.push([/\./g, " "]);
   replacements.push([/([A-Z])/g, " $1"]);
   replacements.push([/Id==/g, " "]);
   replacements.push([/Id=in=\(/g, ' ']);
   replacements.push([/title==/g, 'title: ']);
   replacements.push([/description==/g, 'description: ']);
   replacements.push([/\*/g, ' ']);
   replacements.push([/\)/g, ' ']);
   replacements.push([/\,/g, '']);
   replacements.push([/=/g, '']);
   replacements.push([/>/g, '']);
   replacements.push([/-/g, '']);
   replacements.push([/:/g, '']);
   replacements.push([/[0-9]/g, '']);
   replacements.push([/Z/g, '']);
   
   for (var x = 0, r = replacements[0]; 
       x < replacements.length; 
       r = replacements[++x])
    item = item.replace(r[0], r[1]);
  
  return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1)
}

var items = 'title==*test*;description==*some%20desciption*;eventTypeId==10;studyId==99999;priorityId==2;severityId==3;occuredDate%3E=2016-09-01T04:00:00.000Z'.split(';');

console.log(items.map(filter));
```

Comment: Just only one word - "WOW", thank you a lot! it is not making my code more simple but It definitely makes it better.

Answer (score 1):

It's still gonna need a few layers, but it's possible to simplify this rather drastically:

```
return function(item) {
    var replaced = item.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1")
        .replace(/(title|description)==/g, "$1: ")
        .replace(/Id=(?:in)?=|[.*()]/g, " ")
        .replace(/[\d=>:Z,-]/g, "")
    return replaced.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + replaced.slice(1)
}
```

I might have missed a condition or two, but that's the general idea.

Comment: it makes a string, instead of an array, such in my example, but I got your idea. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can compress many of the regex statements using character classes and OR `|` statements.

There were also a few statements that could be combined.

```js
function filter(item) {
  item = item.replace(/[.)*]|(?:Id)?==/g, ' ')
             .replace(/[,=:>Z\d-]/g, '')
             .replace(/[A-Z]/g, ' $&');

  return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
}

var str = 'title==*test*;description==*some%20desciption*;eventTypeId==10;studyId==99999;priorityId==2;severityId==3;occuredDate%3E=2016-09-01T04:00:00.000Z';

console.log(filter(str));
```